# How to understand random time effect

Tags: mixed-model, fixed-effects-model, cross-correlation

I am reading a slides about correlated random effects [here](https://conference.iza.org/conference_files/SUMS_2013/slides_1_linear_iza.pdf).

The baseline model is
$$
y_{it} = \eta_t + x_{it}\beta + c_i + u_{it}
$$

In page 5, it assumes that we randomly draw sample $i$ from the population. Thus the assumption is saying there is no cross-cluster correlation. Do I understand it correctly?

In page 9, it says that in a setting such as small $N$ and large $T$, we can treat $\eta_t$ as random variables that induces cross sectional correlation. How should I understand this?

I understand that for example, it is common shock to all $i$s at time $t$. But if it induces cross-sectional correlation, does not it violate the assumption of cluster independence? Or because cross-sectional correlation is explicitly modelled by using $\eta_t$ it is not a concern now, and we can use normal standard error?

Comment: $\eta_t$ does indeed induce cross-sectional correlation, but since the effect is assumed to affect all units in the same way, it is easy to account for it with a common time effect in the panel regression, so that, after having controlled for the effect, inference may proceed "as usual"